# LNK2005 template function

Tags: c++, templates

I first implement following functions in the same .cpp file as the main(). Everything works perfectly. But I met some problem when I tried to define them in a header file and implement them in a separate .cpp file.

These are my original code:

```
template <class T> //implement the sum function of one single container
double sum(const T& source){...}

//explicit specialization for map
template<>
double sum<map<string, double>>(const map<string,double>& source){...}

template <class T> //implement the sum function for two iterators
double sum( const class T::const_iterator& start,  const class T::const_iterator& end){...}

//explicit specialization for map (sum function of iterator)
template<>
double sum<map<string, double>>(const map<string, double>::const_iterator& start,const map<string, double>::const_iterator& end){...}

void main(){...}
```

Then I remove the implementation of the functions and define them in a header file:

```
template <class T> //implement the sum function of one single container
double sum(const T& source);

//explicit specialization for map
template<>
double sum<map<string, double>>(const map<string,double>& source);

template <class T> //implement the sum function for two iterators
double sum( const class T::const_iterator& start,  const class T::const_iterator& end);

//explicit specialization for map (sum function of iterator)
template<>
double sum<map<string, double>>(const map<string, double>::const_iterator& start,const map<string, double>::const_iterator& end);
```

and implement them in a .cpp file.

Then when I include both of the header file and cpp file, and run the project:

```
main(){...}
```

I received error message like:

```
sum.obj : error LNK2005: "double __cdecl sum<class std::map<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >....
```

Can anyone give a hint what I might have done wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: Look over there ===> right side of this page under the Related heading.  "Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?" tells you everything you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your problem:

```
double sum<map<string, double>> # <-- here
```

Seems that you are using the ">>" operator, you should give space for avoid that

```
double sum< map<string, double> > # space
```

Comment: No, it is allowed to do that since C++11.

Comment: I didn't see the C++11 tag

Comment: Actually, I think that the C++11 tag is made for specific problems with C++11, not C++ in general. Also this is a linker error, not compiler error - if it would be the problem with >> interpreted as bit shift operator, it would be a compiler error.